# Oracle Client locks up or crashes

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, crash

I am writing a C# Windows Forms application that runs on .NET 3.5, and uses Oracle's client to connect to the database (I wish I could upgrade to .NET 4.0 or later, but I can't). There's a lot of code in the application that follows the usual pattern; here it is in pseudocode:

```
var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

...

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    using(var conn = OpenOracleConnection()) {
        e.Result = LoadSomethingFromDatabase(conn);
    }
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
    DisplayLoadedData(e.Result);
}
```

So far so good. Unfortunately, I've recently added some code that executes such queries quite rapidly, though only on a single thread. And now, the application occasionally exhibits one of the following two behaviors:

- It locks up somewhere in Oracle code, in utterly innocuous methods such as `"reader.GetInt32(string)"`.
- It crashes the entire CLR. There's no exception that I can catch; the entire process dies instantly. In the event viewer, Oracle's DLLs are listed as the faulting modules.

I checked, and there's nothing wrong with my network connection or the Oracle DB itself, as far as I can tell. Nor am I sharing my Oracle connection across threads; while the code in worker.DoWork runs on a background thread from the ThreadPool, that particular "conn" instance is only accessed from a single thread at a time (seeing as it's declared as a local variable within the method that runs on the thread).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this problem, or at least debug it ? Has it ever happened to anyone else ?

**Update:** For what it's worth, I switched my implementation to use a single long-running DB connection for each worker thread, and limited the number of worker threads. This greatly reduced the frequency of this problem popping up, though sadly it did not eliminate the problem completely.

Comment: Correct, but I am not sharing that instance of "conn" across threads; it runs in its own thread, and is then disposed.

Comment: I'm confused here, do you or do you not use BackgroundWorker?

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully clarify what I meant.

Comment: That's a good point, though I only wrote that in lambda format for brevity; in my actual code, I am passing in an instance method. I forgot about the capturing rules, though. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Do you get the exception on RunWorkerCompleted? If so is it possible you're lazy-loading some data in that LoadSomethingFromDatabase method? What is the error you're seeing? Add some exception handling to both the async and Completed implementations

Comment: Mat, does my edited question make sense ? I create the db connection as a local variable within the method that runs on a pool thread. The variable is created on the stack, then disposed at the end of the "using" block, and is then eligible for GC when worker_doWork returns. As far as I understand, this means that worker_doWork could safely run multiple times on multiple threads simultaneously, and each thread would get its own conn instance. But if I'm wrong about this, it would be pretty bad...

Comment: Sten Petrov, I am not getting any exception. The code inside of LoadSomethingFromDatabase either never returns -- due to being locked up on something like "reader.GetInt32" -- or it crashes the entire CLR process. I can't catch any exceptions in that case, because none are thrown; instead, Windows simply destroys the process.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks, I forgot about the "@username" syntax, I'll keep it in mind from now on.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".